# bug or feature? enter method of listener on labeled rule

Tags: antlr4

After playing a bit with parse listeners I found a behaviour I didn't expect.
My question to you is, am I wrong with my expectation and is this behaviour wanted or is it a bug? If the behaviour is wanted, please explain it.

Here the sample grammar:

```
grammar Labeled;

file: stmt;

stmt: stmt '+' stmt # Add
    | stmt '*' stmt # Mult
    | FLOAT         # Value
    | INTEGER       # Value
    ;

FLOAT: '-'? DIGIT* '.' DIGIT+;
INTEGER: '-'? DIGIT+;
COMMENT: (COMMENT_LINE | COMMENT_BLOCK) -> skip;
WS: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;

fragment
DIGIT: [0-9];
COMMENT_LINE: '//' ~'\n'*;
COMMENT_BLOCK: '/*' .*? '*/';`
```

Here the sample listener:

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.NotNull;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestListener extends LabeledBaseListener {

    public static final String ALL_KEY = "All";
    public static final String MULT_KEY = "Mult";
    public static final String ADD_KEY = "Add";
    public static final String VALUE_KEY = "Value";
    public static final String FILE_KEY = "File";


    public Map<String, Integer> enterValues = new HashMap<>();
    public Map<String, Integer> exitValues = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void enterMult(@NotNull LabeledParser.MultContext ctx) {
        addEnter(ALL_KEY);
        addEnter(MULT_KEY);
    }

    @Override
    public void exitMult(@NotNull LabeledParser.MultContext ctx) {
        addExit(ALL_KEY);
        addExit(MULT_KEY);
    }

    @Override
    public void enterValue(@NotNull LabeledParser.ValueContext ctx) {
        addEnter(ALL_KEY);
        addEnter(VALUE_KEY);
    }

    @Override
    public void exitValue(@NotNull LabeledParser.ValueContext ctx) {
        addExit(ALL_KEY);
        addExit(VALUE_KEY);
    }

    @Override
    public void enterFile(@NotNull LabeledParser.FileContext ctx) {
        addEnter(ALL_KEY);
        addEnter(FILE_KEY);
    }

    @Override
    public void exitFile(@NotNull LabeledParser.FileContext ctx) {
        addExit(ALL_KEY);
        addExit(FILE_KEY);
    }

    @Override
    public void enterAdd(@NotNull LabeledParser.AddContext ctx) {
        addEnter(ALL_KEY);
        addEnter(ADD_KEY);
    }

    @Override
    public void exitAdd(@NotNull LabeledParser.AddContext ctx) {
        addExit(ALL_KEY);
        addExit(ADD_KEY);
    }

    // region map helper
    private static void addValue(Map<String, Integer> valueMap, String name) {
        if(valueMap.containsKey(name)) {
            valueMap.put(name, valueMap.get(name) + 1);
        } else {
            valueMap.put(name, 1);
        }
    }

    private void addEnter(String name) {
        addValue(enterValues, name);
    }

    private void addExit(String name) {
        addValue(exitValues, name);
    }
    // endregion
}
```

The main class:

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRFileStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String filePath = args[0];
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRFileStream(filePath);
        LabeledLexer lexer = new LabeledLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream token = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        LabeledParser parser = new LabeledParser(token);

        TestListener testListener = new TestListener();
        parser.addParseListener(testListener);

        parser.file();

        System.out.println("Enter Values:");
        System.out.println(getMapString(testListener.enterValues));

        System.out.println("Exit Values:");
        System.out.println(getMapString(testListener.exitValues));

        System.out.println("End");
    }

    private static String getMapString(Map<?, ?> map) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        for(Map.Entry<?, ?> curEntry: map.entrySet()) {

            buffer.append("Key: " + curEntry.getKey() + "\tValue: " + curEntry.getValue() + "\n");
        }

        String result = buffer.toString();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now when I execute with a file with content:

```
-4 + 8
```

The output will be:

```
Enter Values:
Key: File   Value: 1
Key: Add    Value: 1
Key: All    Value: 2

Exit Values:
Key: Value  Value: 2
Key: File   Value: 1
Key: Add    Value: 1
Key: All    Value: 4

End
```

But I expect this output:

```
Enter Values:
Key: Value  Value: 2
Key: File   Value: 1
Key: Add    Value: 1
Key: All    Value: 4

Exit Values:
Key: Value  Value: 2
Key: File   Value: 1
Key: Add    Value: 1
Key: All    Value: 4

End
```

So as you can see the enterValue() method is never called. After some more tests it seams that the *enterXXX()* method is not be called if there is only ONE Token/Rule in the rule's alternative.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this behavior is expected (or at a minimum, is allowed). The behavior itself as well as the rationale for it are included in the documentation for the `addParseListener` method you used:

[`Parser.addParseListener(ParseTreeListener)`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Parser.html#addParseListener%28org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeListener%29)

Answer (score 1):

To make this work the way you expect it to, use the ParseTreeWalker directly.  Something like:

```
ParseTree tree = parser.json();
jsonListener listener = new jsonListener();
ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
walker.walk(listener, tree);
```

or in your case:

```
LabeledParser parser = new LabeledParser(token);
ParseTree tree = parser.file();

TestListener testListener = new TestListener();
ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
walker.walk(testListener, tree);
```

This will result in enter methods being called for labeled rule alternatives.